# form submission using JQuery Ajax not working in server but working in localhost codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

form submission using Jquery and Ajax not working in server but it works perfectly in localhost. Whats the reason for this. I using Codeigniter framework.

`View`

```
//order.php

<form action="" method="post" id="form_order">
    <p><input type="text" name="due_date" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="name" /></p>
    <p><button type="submit">SAVE</button></p>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        (function($) {
            "use strict";

                $(function() {
                    $('#form_order').validate({
                        rules: {
                            due_date: {
                                required: true
                            },
                            name: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {
                            due_date: {
                                required: "date required"
                            },
                            name: {
                                required: "name required"
                            }
                        },
                        $('#loading').show();

                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                            type:"POST",
                            data: $(form).serialize(),
                            url:"<?php echo base_url("ordercode"); ?>",
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('#loading').hide();
                                $('#success').show();
                                $('#success').html(data);
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                $('#loading').hide();
                                $('#success').show();
                                $('#success').html('Something went wrong. Tryagain later!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

        })(jQuery)
    });
</script>
```

`controller`

```
//Ordercode.php

if($this->input->post('new_order')) {
        $due_date = $this->input->post('due_date');
        $name = $this->input->post('name');

        $add = $this->orders->addOrder($due_date, $name);

        if($add === TRUE) {
            echo 'Order Added.';
        }
        else if($add === FALSE) {
            echo 'Something went wrong. Tryagain later!';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Something went wrong. Tryagain later!';
        }
}
```

`Model`

```
//Orders.php

public function addOrder($due_date_first, $name) {
        $data = array(
            'order_due_date' => $due_date_first,
            'order_name' => $name
        );
        $add = $this->db->insert('tbl_order', $data);

        if($add == 1) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
}
```

The above code works perfectly in localhost but not in server. Server always returns error.

`Output`

`Server :` Something went wrong. Tryagain later!

`Localhost :` Order Added.

Is there any problem in my coding. Why it's not working in server. Is there any solution. Thankyou.

Comment: Obviously there is something wrong with this line: $add = $this->orders->addOrder($due_date, $name);. What is it returning?

Comment: @jeff : In `localhost` it's returning `TRUE`. But in `server` it's showing `Something went wrong. Tryagain later!` from the Jquery.

Comment: check error log on `server` logs files and paste some error log here.

Comment: @FazalRasel : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. But the page is working properly. I have checked.

Comment: you just post error from browser console. Its not that helpful. Ok, Which server you are using?

Comment: @FazalRasel : hostdime

Comment: apache or nginx? I mean which stack?

Comment: @FazalRasel : apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139916/discussion-between-fazal-rasel-and-jithin-varghese).

Comment: Since this is 500 error code you might want to look at https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function($) {
        "use strict";
        $(function() {
            $('#form_order').validate({
                rules: {
                    due_date: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    name: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    due_date: {
                        required: "date required"
                    },
                    name: {
                        required: "name required"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form,e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formData = new FormData(form);
                    $('#loading').show();
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        data: formData,
                        url:"<?php echo base_url("ordercode"); ?>",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#success').show();
                            $('#success').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#success').show();
                            $('#success').html('Something went wrong. Tryagain later!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
});
```

And remove `action=""` attribute in form tag